# How to install wordpress in sub directory in windows azure

Tags: wordpress, azure

I created WordPress site and want to install it in windows azure and haven't the access to server host. 
i searched for this problem and find some links [such tahat](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2011/01/setting-up-wordpress-on-windows-and-sql-azure-a-walkthrough/) but didn't with me correctly it's old version. can help please show to install that as ZIP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial will help you to do that 
http://www.davebost.com/2013/07/10/moving-a-wordpress-blog-to-windows-azure-part-1